# I need to validate a SSN, in a very specific way

Tags: java

So here is my code, I understand that this question or a similar has been posted before. The conflict I've come across is that I'm not supposed to be using "regex". I know that's a more simplistic way of writing this program but it's nothing we've gone over yet in my class. I'm NOT looking for easy answers, just tips.

```
public class SSNValidatorApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String ssn = Validator.getSSN(sc, "Enter a Social Security Number: ");

        System.out.println("You entered: " + ssn);
    }
}
```

So this is the first class to display output,

```
public static boolean isDigit(char c) {
    return Character.isDigit(c);
}

public static boolean isDash(char c) {
    return (c == '-');
}

public static String getSSN(Scanner sc, String prompt) {
    System.out.println(prompt);
    String ssn = sc.next();
    String tryAgain = "y";

    while (tryAgain.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
        if (ssn.length() != 11) {
            System.out.println(ssn + " is not a valid SSN");
            sc.nextLine();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < ssn.length(); i++) {
            if (i <= 2) {
                if (!isDigit(ssn.charAt(i))) {
                    System.out.println(ssn + " is not a valid SSN");
                    sc.nextLine();
                }
                else if (i == 3) {
                    if (!isDash(ssn.charAt(i))) {
                        System.out.println(ssn + " is not a valid SSN");
                        sc.nextLine();
                    }
                }
                else if (i == 6) {
                    if (!isDash(ssn.charAt(i))) {
                        System.out.println(ssn + " is not a valid SSN");
                        sc.nextLine();
                    }

                }
                else if (i > 6) {
                    if (!isDigit(ssn.charAt(i))) {
                        System.out.println(ssn + " is not a valid SSN");
                        sc.nextLine();
                    } 
                }
            }
        }

        tryAgain = Validator.getString(sc, "Would you like to re-enter your SSN? (y/n): ");
        System.out.println();
    }

    return ssn;
}
```

The issue in my code is coming from the end, where it should ask the user "Would you like to re-enter your SSN? where they answer y or n the only issue is that when they answer, it continues to say ""DDD-DD-DDDD" is not a valid SSN". Is this an issue of the mass of if/else if/for/while statements I have?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to debug your code. Everything you output an error message, you don't break from the loop and therefore continue printing error messages.

Comment: Use a regular expression. You can find a lot of different expressions here: http://www.regxlib.com/Search.aspx?k=ssn

Comment: How do you expect `i <= 2` and `i == 3` both to be true?

Comment: Not using a regex here is like not using a hammer to bang in a nail - and whacking the nail with your hand instead.... why??

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl there's the problem of this statement by the OP: `I'm not supposed to be using "regex"`.

Comment: @vikingsteve it's not something my course has gone over yet, we're working with the string class, arrays, stringbuilder, and calendars right now so it wouldn't be right for me to skip over the use of them to the 'easier' functions, even if it is more efficient.

Comment: You do know that it is always better to look ahead and explore topics outside of what you are currently learning. Some professors/instructors encourage you to try out different approaches. You could also try to do this with a regular expression on the side to show the difference between what you are learning. :)

Comment: @Mr. Polywhirl, I guess you're right. ill talk to my instructor about learning further, later today.

Comment: @RonaveCode `String.matches(String regex)` is part of the `String` class. It wouldn't be "skipping ahead".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should query the user for the ssn at the start of the loop, i.e. put `String ssn = sc.next();` right at the top of the while-block.

Currently you are querying the user once and after the while block you reuse the value of `ssn` instead of asking for a new one before validation.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll try to apply it when I get back to my computer.

Comment: Added the while code to the class that has the first block and put the prompt in the beginning and it works smoothly, thank you for the information.

Answer (score 0):

The for loop is quite unnecessary and makes it all a lot more verbose. If you really can't use a regex, just hard-code the conditions on each character:

```
if (ssn.length() != 11
    || !isDigit(ssn.charAt(0))
    || !isDigit(ssn.charAt(1))
    || !isDigit(ssn.charAt(2))
    || !isDash(ssn.charAt(3))
    || !isDigit(ssn.charAt(4))
    || !isDigit(ssn.charAt(5))
    || !isDash(ssn.charAt(6))
    || !isDigit(ssn.charAt(7))
    || !isDigit(ssn.charAt(8))
    || !isDigit(ssn.charAt(9))
    || !isDigit(ssn.charAt(10))) {
  System.out.println( ssn + " is not a valid SSN");
  sc.nextLine();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'll try this once I get back to my computer.

Comment: This block helped with shortening the code tremendously, thank you.